# Prevent Partial Duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, multiple-entries

I have a worksheet with products where the people in my office can add new positions. The problem we're running into is that the products have specifications but not everybody puts them in (or inputs them wrong).

Example:
"cool product 14C"

Is there a way to convert Data Valuation option so that it warns me now in case I put "very cool product 14B" or anything that contains an already existing string of characters (say, longer than 4), like "cool produKt 14C" but also "good product 15" and so on?

I know that I can prevent 100% matches using COUNTIF and spot words that start/end in the same way using LEFT/RIGHT but I need to spot partial matches within the entries as well.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not possible using formulas alone.

Comment: Would it be possible using VBA? And if so, how advanced of a VBA user would I have to be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover typo's, word wraps, figure permutations etc. maybe a [SOUNDEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm would suit to your problem. Here's an [implementation for Excel](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip77.htm) ...

So if you insert this as a user defined function, and create a column `=SOUNDEX(A1)` for each product row, upon entry of a new product name you can filter for all product rows with same SOUNDEX value. You can further automate this by letting user enter the new name into a dialog form first, do the validation, present them a Combo Box dropdown with possible duplicates, etc. etc. etc.

**edit:**

small function to find parts of strings terminated by blanks in a range (in answer to your comment)

```
Function FindSplit(Arg As Range, LookRange As Range) As String
Dim LookFor() As String, LookCell As Range
Dim Idx As Long

    LookFor = Split(Arg)
    FindSplit = ""

    For Idx = 0 To UBound(LookFor)

        For Each LookCell In LookRange.Cells
            If InStr(1, LookCell, LookFor(Idx)) <> 0 Then
                If FindSplit <> "" Then FindSplit = FindSplit & ", "
                FindSplit = FindSplit & LookFor(Idx) & ":" & LookCell.Row
            End If
        Next LookCell
    Next Idx

    If FindSplit = "" Then FindSplit = "Cool entry!"
End Function
```

This is a bit crude ... but what it does is the following

- split a single cell argument in pieces and put it into an array --> `split()`
- process each piece --> `For Idx = ...`
- search another range for strings that contain the piece --> `For Each ...`
- add piece and row number of cell where it was found into a result string

You can enter/copy this as a formula next to each cell input and know immediately if you've done a cool input or not.

[image]

Value of cell D8 is [**asd:3, wer:4**]

Note the use of absolute addressing in the start of lookup range; this way you can copy the formula well down.

**edit 17-Mar-2015**

further to comment Joanna 17-Mar-2015, if the search argument is part of the range you're scanning, e.g. `=FINDSPLIT(C5; C1:C12)` you want to make sure that the `If Instr(...)` doesn't hit if `LookCell` and `LookFor(Idx)` are really the same cell as this would create a false positive. So you would rewrite the statement to

```
...
    ...
        If InStr(1, LookCell, LookFor(Idx)) <> 0 And _
           Not (LookCell.Row = Arg.Row And LookCell.Column = Arg.Column) _
        Then
```

**hint**

Do not use a complete column (e.g. $C:$C) as the second argument as the function tends to become very slow without further precautions

Comment: Typos are the smallest problem. The thing I need more is that the program signals that one of the words typed has already been typed before in this column.

Comment: @Joanna see edit ... works only for strings and substrings ... no typo's caught ;-) (like produ**c**t vs. produ**k**t

Comment: @Joanna glad ... I hope this gests you started and provides enough inspiration to develop your dream function ;-)

Comment: The function works like a charm! One thing I changed was that the products will be added in between as well and so, the function I have
=findsplit(C8;$C:C$) 
to compare it with the whole column. Is there a way to exclude the C8 from $C:$C? I can't seem to find the proper way to do it. I'd like the comparison to be with all the cells in this column except the one I'm writing in.